# Sum each column in csv

Tags: python, csv

Given a csv file

```
A,0,0,1,0
B,0,0,1,0
C,0,0,1,0
D,0,0,1,0
E,0,0,1,0
F,0,0,0,1
```

I'd like to compute the totals for each column. Is there a more pythonic or efficient way to do this than:

```
import csv

totals = [0]*4

for row in csv.reader(csvfile):
    counts = [ int(x) for x in row[-4:] ]
    totals = [ sum(x) for x in zip(counts, totals) ]
print(totals)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a comprehensive way that could do the job without external libs:

```
matrix = [[int(i) for i in row[-4:]] for row in csv.reader(csvfile)]

totals = [sum(array[i] for array in matrix) for i in range(4)]
```

Comment: I'd make `4` a parameter instead of hardcoding it. Otherwise, good solution

Answer (score 5):

transpose the csv file beforehand, skip the now title column and just compute sum on each row

```
cr = zip(*csv.reader(csvfile))
next(cr)

result = [sum(map(int,x)) for x in cr]
print(result)
```

> [0, 0, 5, 1]

careful as it loads the whole file in memory when expanding the arguments for `zip`, though.

Answer (score 1):

Use pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('path/to/file.csv', header=None, index_col=0)
df.sum()
```

here is a sample using StringIO

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

s = """A,0,0,1,0
B,0,0,1,0
C,0,0,1,0
D,0,0,1,0
E,0,0,1,0
F,0,0,0,1"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), header=None, index_col=0)
print(df.sum())

1    0
2    0
3    5
4    1
```

Comment: While a valid solution, if OP is not already using `pandas` in this project then this is a huge overkill

Answer (score 1):

You can use [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/index.html)'s [`genfromtxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.20/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) to read the file, then slice the index column and [`sum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) the array:

```py
import numpy as np

my_data = np.genfromtxt(csvfile, delimiter=',')
print(my_data[:,1:].sum(axis=0))
```

Gives:

```
[0. 0. 5. 1.]
```